20.04.6 LTS: Touchpad turns into mouse after some time
I recently purchased a Huawei Matebook D14 2023. I installed on an external SSD Ubuntu 20.04 and everything seems to work fine.
I can use the touchpad without any issues, I can scroll with two finger, right click with two fingers too, etc. However, randomly after some time using the PC, the touchpad stops supporting any gestures, just moving the mouse. Also the mouse speed changes to the one configured in "Mouse Speed" instead of "Touchpad Speed", and the touchpad configuration is enabled, so I've suspected it becomes recognized as a mouse.
In the output given by xinput it seems like it is recognized as both mouse and touchpad:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ BLTP7840:00 347D:7840 Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ BLTP7840:00 347D:7840 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Camera: HD Camera                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Huawei WMI hotkeys                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sennheiser Communications  Sennheiser USB headset id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

I've tried to disable the BLTP7840:00 347D:7840 Mouse but then nothing works. I've also tried solutions for similar topics in other threads like doing:
sudo  modprobe -r psmouse

sudo  modprobe psmouse

and nothing worked. The only thing that works is rebooting or sometimes sleeping and waking up the computer.

A new computer may run a newer version of Ubuntu better.

@DavidDE yes but I need that version of Ubuntu
